# Voice Chat over Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, voip

I have done some research on Voice Chat using Bluetooth and have gone through the Bluetooth article here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html but couldn't found anything related to Voice Chat.

I have seen an application on Play Store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.okean.btcom) providing same functionality that means Voice Chat is possible using Bluetooth in Android.

I have also seen Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) provides Voice Chat Service but it uses Internet data. I want it over Bluetooth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have gone through sipdroid project here http://sipdroid.org/ but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

On a motorcycle or loud boat a headset would provide clear communications within Bluetooth range.  Yelling is impractical and stressful.

Motorcycle comm systems often use BT, but the systems are designed to work on helmets and are propietary.  There are instances in a high noise environment where a BT headset or earpiece would be more practical.

An app on a phone or some sort of Bluetooth hub could work in high noise confined environment.

Answer (score -5):

If you are in bluetooth range, why not just voice chat over air? as in sound pressure, aka human speech?

Comment: oh and bluetooth also provides audio profile, thus 2-way chat is already there if the other end is a headset.